# How to make a loop which ignores letters in C?

Tags: c

C noob here. Just ignore the title couldn't find a better one :D

```
void displayMainMenu() {
int choice;
do {
    printf("1. Start the game.\n");
    printf("2. Recruit troops.\n");
    printf("3. Exit.\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
} while (choice < 1 || choice > 3);
switch (choice) {
    case(1) : printf("...");
    break;
    case(2) : printf("...");
    break;
    case(3) : printf("...");
    exit(0);
    break;
}
}
```

When I enter a a number out of the range it loops perfectly fine, but when I enter a letter or a symbol, it gets to an infinite loop. I want my programs to be perfect even though I am a beginner so I was wondering how can I achieve this? Should I use ASCII or is there a complete different method of doing this kind of thing.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");//add
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine thanks for the solution. I am assuming it is some kind of regex or some pointer stuff. I would really appreciate if you could explain it too :)

Comment: @thephysicsguy It is not a regular expression in `scanf`, but you can simple pattern matching. `%*[^\n]` skip the character except a newline. `%*c` skip the character(remain newline). This means that I will skip it if there is an input of extra characters.

Answer (score 2):

Reason why it goes infinite: the `scanf` rejects a letter for `"%d"` and nothing's read. Notice that didn't consumes the letter in the input buffer, so the next time `scanf` is invoked it fails again.

To know more about this, check the return value of `scanf`: `0` or `EOF` for nothing read, `1` for 1 item read.

So the solution would be to examine the return value of `scanf` and break out of the loop.

#### EDITED:

An example added:

```
do {
    printf("1. Start the game.\n");
    printf("2. Recruit troops.\n");
    printf("3. Exit.\n");
    int item_got = scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (item_got != 1)
    {
        choice = -1; // mark it.
        break;
    }
} while (choice < 1 || choice > 3);
```

Comment: As mentioned, scanf can return numbers other than zero on failure, read the manpage.

Comment: I found BLUEPIXYs answer to work fine, however yours seems to be an alternate way. I am not even sure how I would get what scanf returns though, if I do I may integrate it to the while condition like you said.

Comment: @starrify yes this is very close but it breaks the loop. I would like it to continue...

Comment: @thephysicsguy Fine, then BLUEPIXY's approach would do. Also since you have few options, you could read a character instead of an integer.

Comment: I think the example you have is still going to leave what might be trash in the input stream.  In most cases your best bet is to trash everything up to the newline.  Scanf alone really doesn't handle this very well - you'd be better off reading in the entire line (if you're expecting a newline at the end) and then using sscanf(), or going down to the getchar() level.

Answer (score 0):

As scanf() function returns 0 if fails to read formatted input. So if you want to exit when user enter this kind of input then you can write:

```
if(!scanf("%d", &choice))break;
```